# Getting H2OValueError: Unknown parameter metalearner_params = {'ntrees': 100, 'max_depth': 3} in H2O stacked ensemble

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I am using the example provided in the H2O [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/metalearner_params.html) to define the grid parameters in the H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator object with two base models and meta-learner. However, it returns an error whenever i pass the grid params. Below is the code sample for reference.

```
gbm_params = {"ntrees": 100, "max_depth": 3}

stack_gbm = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=[RF_model, XGB_model],
                                        metalearner_algorithm="gbm",
                                        metalearner_params=gbm_params)

stack_gbm.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
H2OValueError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-ebd1246afa1b> in <module>
      3 stack_gbm = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=[RF_model, XGB_model],
      4                                         metalearner_algorithm="gbm",
----> 5                                         metalearner_params=gbm_params)
      6 
      7 stack_gbm.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/estimators/stackedensemble.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     61                 setattr(self, pname, pvalue)
     62             else:
---> 63                 raise H2OValueError("Unknown parameter %s = %r" % (pname, pvalue))
     64         self._parms["_rest_version"] = 99
     65 

H2OValueError: Unknown parameter metalearner_params = {'ntrees': 100, 'max_depth': 3}
```

Comment: I tested the documentation example for GBM, RF, and XGBoost on H2O (3.30.0.4) and did not get the error. Can you share your code on how the models were built? What version are you using (`metalearner_params` was added in H2O 3.18)? Are you able to reproduce the error with the example data or with different base models?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using H2o version '3.16.0.2'. Is it not possible to perform hyper-parameter tuning over the meta-classifier in that case?

Comment: Can you try the latest version and see if you still have the same issue?